# Verilog - how to overcome the fact that I cannot mixed edge and level triggers,writing to memory

Tags: integrated-circuit, verilog

I have a 32x32 ram module which i built, the simple code:

### Verilog Code

```
module RAM32X32(
    input clk,
    input rst,
    input WE,
    input [4:0] ADDRESS,
    input [31:0] D_IN,
    output  [31:0] D_OUT
    );
//////internal//////////////// 
reg [31:0] mem [31:0];//,r;
wire [31:0] data ;
integer i;
/////////////////////////////

initial begin 
  for (i = 0; i < 32; i = i +1) begin
      mem[i] = 32'b0;  
  end
end
assign data = WE ? D_IN : 32'bz;

always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if  (WE == 1'b1) begin 
        mem[ADDRESS] = data;
    end
end
assign D_OUT = mem[ADDRESS]; 
endmodule
```

now I see that when I writing to the ram, It takes time, and in the simulation I see the memory changes just the CC after, as seen below (R31 is in the last row, there i want to write):

[image]

So i changes my sensitivity list and added:

```
(posedge clk or data)
```

And I got what I wanted in the simulation.
But....synthasize didnt allowed it because of :

> No support for synthesis of mixed edge and level triggers.

So i thought of doing a level triggered ram with tri-state to protect him.
What do you think? is it even legit to use level triggered this days?
Any help will be helpful!

Thanks!!

Comment: Your test bench is setting up WE and the address after the first positive edge of a clock. The clock transitions low (and nothing happens as expected) and then high again at which time the write happens, because now WE is valid and you have a positive edge. If you wanted it to happen earlier, you'd need to set up the inputs prior to the previous positive edge. That's something you can resolve in the test bench.

Comment: The write to `mem` is synchronous, therefore you should use non-blocking assignment (`<=`) instead of blocking (`=`). What is the point of making `data` tri-state? Why not drop `data` and do `if (WE==1'b1) begin mem[ADDRESS] <= D_IN; end`?

Comment: You are going about this in a mistaken manner.  What you have observed is that a synchronous system has a pipeline delay.  But in trying to make an asynchronous system, you'll just end up with something slower and harder to correctly model.  What you need to do is to learn to design with the pipeline delay.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been abandoned by the asker for two years

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your testbench because you have a simulation race condition. Use non-blocking assignments to your inputs, or change your inputs on the negative edge of the clock. That way they will be settled in the RAM inputs before the posedge clock.

Comment: Thanks, I have a delay in the testbench,but it's intended, because this is going to the fpga,and the fpga got delay, and I want to see how it handles with the delay, and I had a problem with writing to the ram in the fpga.
And I wil try the negedge idea!